# How to set StartDate of EndDate datepicker based on StartDate datepicker selected value in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

I am working on AngularJS. I am trying to dynamically generate rows when user clicks on "Add New Row" button. Here is my `$scope` array variable,

```
$scope.avails = [{"Name":"","startdate":"","enddate":""}];

$scope.addNewRow=function() {
   $scope.avails.push({"Name":"","startdate":"","enddate":""});
}
```

and here is my markup

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="ff in avails">
   <label>Name</label>
   <input type="text" ng-model="ff.Name"/>
   <label>Start Date</label>
   <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" b-datepicker name="startdate" id="startdate{{$index}}" ng-model="ff.startdate" value="{{ff.startdate}}" placeholder="Start Date" >
   </div>
   <label>End Date</label>
   <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" b-datepicker name="startdate" id="startdate{{$index}}" ng-model="ff.startdate" value="{{ff.startdate}}" placeholder="Start Date" >
   </div>
<div>
```

and I write a `directive` for date picker like:

```
.directive('bDatepicker', function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: '?ngModel',
      link: function(scope, el, attr,ngModel) {     
         ngModel.$render = function() { 
            el.datepicker('update', ngModel.$viewValue || '');
         };

         el.datepicker({
            autoclose:true,
            format:'mm/dd/yyyy'
         }).on('changeDate', function(value) {
            var dateStrToSend = (value.date.getMonth() + 1) +'/'+value.date.getDate()+'/'+value.date.getFullYear();
            scope.$apply(function () {
               ngModel.$setViewValue(dateStrToSend);
            });     

            $(".datepicker").hide();
         });
      }
   };
})
```

Now I am able to create a new row when user clicks on `Add New` Button, Each row contains start and end date pickers, when user select a date under start date picker, I need to set that date as startdate of corresponding end date picker.

Since I am applying directive to element as a attribute, how to change value of another element from this directive?

Comment: Use https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date you can then set ui-date="{ minDate: whatever.startdate }"

Answer (score 3):

This is what I used to solve the problem.
Basically you set the "min" value on the end date input to the selected value of the start date.

Start Date

```
<input type="text" id="start-date" class="form-control" placeholder="Start Date"
datepicker-options="UI.datepickerOptions"
datepicker-popup="yyyy-MM-dd"
ng-model="MODEL.date_start"
ng-required="true">
```

End Date

```
<input type="text" id="end-date" class="form-control" placeholder="End Date"datepicker-options="UI.datepickerOptions"
 datepicker-popup="yyyy-MM-dd"
 ng-model="MODEL.date_end"
 min="MODEL.date_start"
 ng-required="true">
```

And the controller where we watch for changes on the first datepicker:

```
// update the end date based on the start date
$scope.$watch('MODEL.date_start', function (newVal, oldVal) {
  if(!newVal) return;

  // if the new start date is bigger than the current end date .. update the end date
  if($scope.MODEL.date_end){
    if( +$scope.MODEL.date_end < +$scope.MODEL.date_start ){
      $scope.MODEL.date_end = newVal;
    }
  } else {
    // just set the end date
    $scope.MODEL.date_end = newVal;
  }

});
```

Edit: I'm using the Angular UI Bootstrap datepicker http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

Answer (score 1):

Modify the directive to optionally take the `minDate` into account. E.g.:

```
.directive('bDatepicker', function($parse){ // ADD DEPENDENCY ON $parse
    //...other code the same...
    link: function(scope, el, attr,ngModel) {
        //...other code the same...
        if( attr.minDate != null && attr.minDate != "" ) {
            scope.$watch($parse(attr.minDate), function(newval) {
                el.datepicker("option", "minDate", newval);
            });
        }
    }
```

Use it as:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" b-datepicker min-date="ff.startDate"
    name="endDate" id="endDate{{$index}}" ng-model="ff.endDate"
    placeholder="End Date" />
```

The same principle can be used for the max date as well.

By the way, specifying `value` with `ng-model` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Try This One

```
            $('#SDate').datepicker({
                minDate: 0,
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                    $("#EDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                }
            });
            $('#EDate').datepicker({
                minDate: 0,
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                    $("#SDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
                }
            });
```